# How to clear search history in Apple Maps

Tags: iphone, maps

I’m on iOS 11 and to sliding an entry to the left is supposed to remove the entry. Now that the clear all option is gone I have to do it one by one, which is okay, but the problem is it doesn’t work.

The entry comes back immediately and it only works for new entries.

Is there any way to clear the history, or probably reset the app entirely? Reinstalling the app doesn’t work - the history comes back up.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have iCloud enabled, and it keeps putting the removed entries back

1. Settings app
2. Select your Apple ID
3. Tap iCloud
4. Scroll down to Maps
5. Toggle it off

Then go back to Maps and swipe to delete.